# Should RESTful 'PATCH' operation return something?

Tags: web-services, rest, resources, patch

I am struggling what is the best practice for PATCH method.

I see couple of possibilities:

1. Return HTTP status code `200 OK` with updated object.
2. Return HTTP status code `204 No Content`.

*What would be the best one?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.1) states:

> The 204 response code is used because the response does not carry a
> message body (which a response with the 200 code would have).  Note
> that other success codes could be used as well.

Which just means you may decide to return a body or not, the response codes should then be `200` or `204` respectively. Neither is better or worse than the other. You may find that it is practical to just return the changed content, so the client does not have to make a new request to get the new content.

Note: using the `PATCH` is quite tricky, as you must define a `mime-type` for applying change-sets to your resource. This may not be what you want. More often than not, `PATCH` can be solved by just creating a new resource that should have been a resource anyway.

Comment: In general you would vote to return an updated object:) Using PATCH in my application seems not to be too tricky, however, still some special actions needed to be done.

Comment: you must also remember to deal with Etag and if-match headers to deal with concurrent updates while using PATCH